# OTF font not uploded in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming, mime-types

I want to upload the custom fonts in WordPress dashboard. When I try to upload the font file, it is showing the error:

```
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

Then I have allowed the font all files by using below code:

```
  add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
  function add_custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
    $existing_mimes['otf'] = 'application/x-font-opentype';
    $existing_mimes['woff'] = 'application/x-font-woff';
    $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'application/x-font-ttf';
    $existing_mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $existing_mimes['eot'] = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject';
    return $existing_mimes;
  }
```

Now all type of font get uploaded but when I upload the .otf font it is showing me the same error.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blow is the step to resolved this issue.

Open the wp-config.php file of your WordPress installation and above the line where it says /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ add the following code anywhere:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

reference: https://tribulant.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-fix-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons/

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
$existing_mimes['otf'] = 'font/otf';
```

or

```
$existing_mimes['otf'] = 'application/font-sfnt';
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since You made this post. But I'm using a plugin called "WP Add Mime Types".

And as a value in plugin settings (Settings -> Myme Type Settings) I added this: **otf = application/x-font-opentype**

It's working for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used following code, and it's worked properly.

```php
    add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
    function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes ) {

        $existing_mimes['ttf'] = 'application/x-font-ttf';
        $existing_mimes['woff'] = 'application/x-font-woff';
        $existing_mimes['woff2'] = 'application/x-font-woff2';
        $existing_mimes['otf'] = 'application/x-font-otf';
        return $existing_mimes;
    }
```